# order mismatch while Loading part files as input in pig script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

when i try to load output of pig script in another pig script order of loading the data loaded is changing

i have 5 part files in my output of pig script-1

```
part-r-00000
part-r-00001
part-r-00002
part-r-00003
part-r-00004
```

i want to load this part files in another script in order of part file names
when i load this output of pig script-1 in pig script-2
data loaded is not in order of part files, i loaded this output as below

```
SET default_parallel 5;
A = LOAD 'Output' USING PigStorage(‘,’) AS (f1:int, f2:int, f3:int);

Dump A;

DATA in part-r-00000
DATA in part-r-00001
DATA in part-r-00004
DATA in part-r-00003
DATA in part-r-00002
```

and this order of loading data is changing everytime

is there any solution to load data in order of part file names?

i cant think of any but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to load in order, Even if you load in order maps are going to work only on block level.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana i have to load files in order to add extra field ROW id to each record and this row id is 1 for first record, 2 for second record and similarly 100 for 100th record according to part files data . Is there any solution to maintain and order ?

Comment: My guess that it might be because of the number of reducers you are having can you remove "SET default_parallel 5" and then check.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana Thanks for the reply .
i should have to use Parallel 5.if i remove the parallel 5 performance issue will be there. i can able to run the pig script if i remove 'SET default_parallel 5'. Is there any solution to maintain an order while running through multiple reducers ?

Comment: If you want the output in order then you should sort the data before dumping it that is the only option since you want multiple reducers.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana i tried by ordering before dumping , it worked thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

you can load all the part files using

`xyz = LOAD 'output_path/part-*' using PigStorage() AS (f1:int, f2:int, f3:int);`

but this doesn't guarantee you that it will load all the part files in an order, here we are just specifying to load all the part files.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I tried the way you suggested but i couldn't load the files in order.
is there any other solution to load the data and maintain order ?

Comment: You can get ordered data only after loading the data but if still you want to process files in a sequence you have to pass the argument at run time and process each file at a time. Else apply order by after loading the data. Because HDFS will never assure you to read data in a order.